# Rotate player to vector3 point?

Tags: unity, rotate

I want my player object rotate to face vector3 point on terrain.

```
public Vector3 RocketPointer;
public Transform pointer,Player;
public bool rocket_, button_move;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (button_move == true)
    {
        Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit mousePoint;

        if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out mousePoint, 100))
        {
            RocketPointer = mousePoint.point;
            pointer.transform.position = RocketPointer;
        }

        if (button_move == true && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
        // rotate player object to face rocketpointer point
            rocket_ = true;
            button_move = false;
        }

    }

    if (button_move == false && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        rocket_ = false;
    }

}

public void move_button() // UI button
{
    button_move = !button_move;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a handy convenience method for this: [`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html).

Assuming `player` is your player game object:

```
player.transform.LookAt(RocketPointer);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Now is rotate and if anyone want to use smooth rotation use "Quaternion.Slerp"